# Django version of request.args.get() function in Flask

Tags: python, django

I am migrating my code from Flask to Django and this line from Flask doesn't seem to work in Django

```
auth_token = request.args['code']
```

I googled a lot but can't seem to find the correct parameter to request the authorization token!

Answer (score 4):

`request.args` in flask is a dictionary-like object based on the *querystring*. In Django, this is `request.GET`, so:

```
auth_token = request.GET['code']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually used it with small letters, but apparent it is a request type here!

Answer (score 2):

@Willem Van Onsem has the right answer here, however you should use the `.get()` function and define a default if the variable doesn't exist, otherwise a KeyError will be raised.

```
auth_token = request.GET.get('code', None)
if auth_token is None:
    # No auth token in request
    return HttpResponse("No Auth Code", status=400)
```